# Calculating log odds with multiple predictor variables in Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, logistic

I'm trying to calculate the log odds of unemployment (1 = employed, 0 = unemployed) based on the age and education (1 = university-educated, 0 = not university-educated) of a sample based on these coefficients:

```
(Intercept)   -3.20      
age            0.08     
uni_educated   0.33
```

I understand how this works using just age as a predictor, i.e. for a 25 year olds, 3.20 + 0.08 * 25 but I'm not sure how to incorporate the second predictor. I realize this is a very basic question but I haven't been able to come up with a solution. Grateful for any pointers.

(I've only included the coefficients because I suspect that's the only needed information, but feel free to let me know if I'm wrong)

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is convert the coefficients into the regression equation and then just do the arithmetic.  Here is the fitted model:
$$
\ln\bigg(\frac{p}{1-p}\bigg) = -3.2 + 0.08\text{ age} + 0.33\text{ uni_educated}
$$
You need to know (or check if you don't) what level of `uni_educated` is the reference level.  I assume it is `did not graduate from university`.  From here, if you want the log odds of someone who did not graduate, you multiply $.33\times 0$ and add that to the rest; if the person did graduate, you multiply $.33\times 1$ and add that to the rest.